# Why My hamburger icon in android app is not working it is not opening the navigation menu?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, navigation-drawer

I am working on an app but there is a problem with hamburger icon as it is not working. It is not opening the navigation menu when i am clicking on it. what is the problem please tell me? I am trying to solve it but dont know what is the problem with it. I am new to code please help me.

**Here is my fragment code**

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment{


NavigationView navigationView;
ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle;
DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
Toolbar toolbar;

private int[] images;
private SliderAdapter sliderAdapter;


public HomeFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

    navigationView = view.findViewById(R.id.navmenu);
    drawerLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.drawerlayout);
    toolbar = view.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

    ActionBar mActionBar;
    ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    Objects.requireNonNull(((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar()).setTitle("");


    toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(getActivity(), drawerLayout, R.string.open, R.string.close);
    drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();
    
    ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.menu3);

    return view;


}
}
```

**Here is my XML file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/drawerlayout"
tools:openDrawer="start"
android:background="@color/white"
tools:context=".HomeFragment">

<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/reddark"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:src="@drawable/backsssososos" />

        </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/search_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
            android:background="@color/reddark"
            android:padding="10dp"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/searchbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/searchbardesign"
                android:backgroundTint="#F8F8F8"
                android:drawableLeft="@android:drawable/ic_menu_camera"
                android:drawableRight="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
                android:drawablePadding="22dp"
                android:gravity="left|center"
                android:hint="Enter City,Colony name..."
                android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textColorHint="@android:color/darker_gray"
                android:textSize="16dp" />
        </RelativeLayout>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>


        <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:id="@+id/nestedScrollView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clipToPadding="true"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <com.smarteist.autoimageslider.SliderView
                    android:id="@+id/imageSlider"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="300dp"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:sliderAnimationDuration="600"
                    app:sliderAutoCycleDirection="back_and_forth"
                    app:sliderAutoCycleEnabled="true"
                    app:sliderIndicatorAnimationDuration="600"
                    app:sliderIndicatorGravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
                    app:sliderIndicatorMargin="15dp"
                    app:sliderIndicatorOrientation="horizontal"
                    app:sliderIndicatorPadding="3dp"
                    app:sliderIndicatorRadius="2dp"
                    app:sliderIndicatorSelectedColor="#5A5A5A"
                    app:sliderIndicatorUnselectedColor="#FFF"
                    app:sliderScrollTimeInSec="1"
                    app:sliderStartAutoCycle="true" />


                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/text_file_2"></TextView>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/text_file_2">

                </TextView>
            </LinearLayout>

        </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>


<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navmenu"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:itemIconTint="@color/black"
    android:theme="@style/NavigationDrawerStyle"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/navheader"
    app:itemTextColor="#151515"
    app:menu="@menu/navigationmenu">

</com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView>
</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must attach toolbar in ActionBarDrawerToggle

```
mDrawerToogle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer,toolbar,R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
            bar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
            bar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            mDrawerToogle.syncState();
            drawer.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToogle);
```

Comment: thank you soo much Vijay Bhai, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

you have to handle this action by yourself

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
        drawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

also `syncState()` call should be placed in `onPostCreate` or even in `onResume`

btw. your empty constructor should at least call `super();`